# Starting Application on iPad right after complete boot

Tags: objective-c, ipad, process

I am thinking to develop an app for iPad which will start after boot. I got few questions as how should I proceed with that.

1. Is there a service way to do that? Like running a service in the background and then on service start, load the app using app registered URI.
2. Can there be local push notification that would either open the app or ask the user to open the app?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to accomplish 1) on a non-jailbroken iPad.

My strong suspicion is that there is no way to tie a notification to the boot of the device, but I am not 100% certain on that.